# Sortable not changing ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to be able, when I drag and drop, to replace all ids by the other.

For example in this code :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="row_0">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form id="form_0" onsubmit="return false;">
        <select class="select2" name="test1" id="test1_0">
          <option value="o_test">o_test1_1</option>
          <option value="o_test">o_test1_2</option>
          <option value="o_test">o_test1_3</option>
        </select>
        <select class="select2" name="test2" id="test2_0">
          <option value="o_test">o_test2_1</option>
          <option value="o_test">o_test2_2</option>
          <option value="o_test">o_test2_3</option>
        </select>

        <button onclick="addRow()">clone</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="row_1">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form id="form_1" onsubmit="return false;">
        <select class="select2" name="test1" id="test1_1">
          <option value="o_test">o_test1_1</option>
          <option value="o_test">o_test1_2</option>
          <option value="o_test">o_test1_3</option>
        </select>
        <select class="select2" name="test2" id="test2_1">
          <option value="o_test">o_test2_1</option>
          <option value="o_test">o_test2_2</option>
          <option value="o_test">o_test2_3</option>
        </select>

        <button onclick="addRow()">clone</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to change when I drag and drop all `id="form_0"` <-> `id="form_1"`,`id="row_0"` <-> `id="row_1"`, `id="test1_0"` <-> `id="test1_1"` .. etc, this is just an example, there are more.

I know that we can use the `stop` option like so :

```
$('.container').sortable({
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    var moved = ui.item,
      replaced = ui.item.prev();

    if (replaced.length == 0) {
      replaced = ui.item.next();
    }

    var moved_num = parseInt(moved.attr("id").match(/\d+/g), 10) + 1;
    var replaced_num = parseInt(replaced.attr("id").match(/\d+/g), 10) + 1;

    moved.find('[id]').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        split = $this.prop('id').split('_')[0];
      $this.prop('id', $this.prop('id').split('_')[0] + '_' + replaced_num);
    });
    replaced.find('[id]').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        split = $this.prop('id').split('_')[0];
      $this.prop('id', $this.prop('id').split('_')[0] + '_' + moved_num);
    });

  }
});
```

The idea here in the code above, is to get the id number of the one moved and replaced, and for each id, replace in each one of them the number of the other.

But it doesn't do what I'm trying to do. Any idea why?

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/763opz0c/

Comment: Why would you need to change the id's in the first place?

Comment: @charlietfl good question, because I'm using a system where I'm generating data depending on the order of the `_X`. So when I change the order, I need to also change that information so the data would turn out correct. It's kinda hard to explain as the example above only explains a small part, the one I need fixed.

Comment: So you would update wherever that system stores the order of items

Comment: @charlietfl actually the idea here is to change the `_X` so when I click on my button that generates data they get generated in the right order. I feel like I'm almost there, but I can't see why isn't my code working, as my logic behind it seems to be okay. I'll explain my logic in an edit.

Comment: Sure you can , just seems more complicated than it needs to be doing it though. Can't you just use indexing? Anyway...create a runnable demo so can see what's going on in dev tools console

Comment: @charlietfl I can't, it really only has to be this way, as I can't go around changing the whole code to satisfy just this problem... Any hint would be greatly appreciated! :) I'll create a jsfiddle

Comment: @charlietfl created

Comment: So just change the id by the index so id's will all be in order?

Comment: @charlietfl yes, replace all the ids ending with `_X` by one another

Comment: To me is simpler to just loop through the whole container and use index to update all id's https://jsfiddle.net/763opz0c/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is loop through all items and use their index within the container to update all id's

```
$('.container').sortable({
  stop: function(event, ui) {
     var $items = $(ui.item).parent().children()
     $items.each(function(index){
         $(this).find('[id]').add(this).attr('id', function(){
             return this.id.split('_')[0] +'_' + index 
         });
     });     
  }
});
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/763opz0c/3/)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! (sorry for the late reply...)